# NPR's Weekend Edition Sunday Puzzle

Tags: wordplay

This was presented on NPR's Weekend Edition by Will Shortz. I've been trying for days and have no clue. You can see the puzzle under "Next Week's Challenge" [here](https://www.npr.org/2018/09/16/648317623/sunday-puzzle-tba)

The following two word phrases having something very unusual in common.  What is it? And when you find it, think of another two word phrase that has the same property.

- Property Rights
- Land Mine
- Sales Order
- Color Scheme
- India Ink

I will be able to verify after the next episode of NPR's Weekend Edition this upcoming Sunday. (September 24th, 2018).

Comment: Could it have anything to do with this topic? https://www.indianbureaucracy.com/scheme-for-intellectual-property-rights-awareness/

Comment: I actually just figured it out.  I'll give it a bit to see if anyone else comes up with it

Comment: For the record, deletion of my semi-jokey answer of RADIO SILENCE is semi-unfair. Please note that it does fit the criteria of _think of another two word phrase that has the same property_, because I believe it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing they have in common is

> The first three letters of the first word are the first three letters of a U.S. state capital.  The first two letters of the second word are the postal abbreviation for that state.

Hence,

> **Pro**perty **Ri**ghts => Providence, RI
> **Lan**d **Mi**ne => Lansing, MI
> **Sal**es **Or**der => Salem, OR
> **Col**or **Sc**heme => Columbia, SC
> **Ind**ia **In**k => Indianapolis, IN

And another combination that would share that property would be

> **Mon**thly **Al**lowance => Montgomery, AL

Comment: Mon and Mob? mistype?

Comment: @ITAlex lol, yes.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the complete answer, but they are all of the form

> Noun modifier, Noun - where the second noun can also be used as a verb

Comment: Sorry, but wrong track